# Android JSON without deprecated HttpClient

Tags: json, android-studio, httpclient

I'm looking for a sample project that demonstrates how to incorporate a remote JSON object into an android application without using the now deprecated HttpClient.  It needs to work on SDK version 14 and up.  Its been difficult finding anything.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to use HttpURLConnection instead.

```
HttpURLConnection   conn    = null;
 
OutputStream          os   = null;
InputStream           is   = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
 
conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(CONN_TIMEOUT * 1000);
conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT * 1000);
conn.setRequestMethod(POST);
conn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
 
JSONObject job = new JSONObject();
job.put("id", "asdf");
job.put("pw", "asdf");
 
os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(job.toString().getBytes());
os.flush();
 
String response;
 
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
 
if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
 
    is = conn.getInputStream();
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
    byte[] byteData = null;
    int nLength = 0;
    while((nLength = is.read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.length)) != -1) {
        baos.write(byteBuffer, 0, nLength);
    }
    byteData = baos.toByteArray();
     
    response = new String(byteData);
     
    JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(response);
    Boolean result = (Boolean) responseJSON.get("result"); 
    String age = (String) responseJSON.get("age");
    String job = (String) responseJSON.get("job");
     
    Log.i(TAG, "DATA response = " + response);
}
```